# Launchctl command line equivalent of "absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier("com.bundle.helper")

Tags: swift, cocoa, launchd, launchctl

On OS X, I'm looking for a command line which would show the known path of a bundleIdentifier from Launch Services point of view.

If there're several bundles with same id, my app keep looking for a trashed one, or copied, and it's hard to troubleshoot without a command like "launchctl .... mybundleId"

In swift, I've found:
let launchdPathToHelper = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().absolutePathForAppBundleWithIdentifier(bundleIdHelper)

This helps me and gives me the answer, but sure there's a command line for that.

Thanks!

Comment: Using `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -dump` gives you the needed info. Sadly there is no way to query or filter the results easily.

Comment: `mdfind -attr kMDItemCFBundleIdentifier 'kMDItemFSName=*.app'` gives you all bundle identifiers alongside its paths from Spotlight. But Spotlight does not include the contents of packges. Thus your helper app probably won't be found.